# Can I provide meta tags within .htaccess on a 301 redirect?

Tags: apache2, redirect, metadata, .htaccess

I have a specific directory on my server:

> [www.example.com/myfavrockgroup](http://www.example.com/myfavrockgroup)

Within .htaccess of my server I am doing a 301 redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /myfavrockgroup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Go-Go%27s
```

The proper meta data from the wikipedia page is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/The_Go_Gos_in_2012.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Go-Go&#039;s - Wikipedia"/>
```

However, if I post my link: **[www.example.com/myfavrockgroup](http://www.example.com/myfavrockgroup)** onto Twitter or Facebook, the 301 redirect does not grab the meta tags from Wikipedia, instead it looks no further than my server.

Is there a way around this? Anyway to program within the .htaccess to grab the proper meta tags from the wiki page?

Linux is far from my forte, at most I can use it just enough to keep a server at home.

Thank you

Comment: What "meta tags" are you referring to specifically? But a fundamental issue here is that a compliant HTTP user-agent (ie. FB or Twitter when examining the shared link) should not be examining the "meta tags" of a redirect response. (?) The issue might be that the redirect response is not actioned to begin with?

Comment: @Levente I have reworded my question, I hope this helps.  Thank you

Comment: Ah, so the social medias are not using the preview images / text you hope they would. But, in this case, if you linked the wikipedia page directly, would these preview elements get picked up as expected? (Why not link the wikipedia article then? Why the _trick_ with your server? You wanna do your "own analytics" by counting traffic on it?) Do Face / Twitter even support looking up `og` meta tags when a redirect is involved? And no, as far as I know, no API dealing with any sort of Apache redirects can handle meta tags.

Comment: Also: if this example would be real, then there seemed to be no _good_ reason not to post a direct link to the wikipedia article. If you really used a redirect on your website to point to a wikipedia article, that would semantically suggest that the article was first written on your website, and then it had gotten moved to wikipedia afterwards. Plus, you seem to expect Wikipedia to provide preview elements (credibility?) to a link leading to _your_ website. If I was working in fraud prevention, I would already have a suspicious eye on such a pattern. Maybe it's purposefully not working.

Comment: @Levente Why does it have to be a fraud instead of a service? Bit.ly for example.

Comment: Back in the day when I was more involved with this it was possible to tell search engine bots (also face / twitter agents?) and real users apart. It would then be possible to do the innocent redirect when a search bot requests the page, but behave differently when a real user visits. E.g. serving some malicious content or something. All the while the `og` meta preview elements would make it look legit. Now of course this is just like, theorizing. And yes, I don't know how bit.ly comes into the picture... All I suggest, there might be some policy behind it. Plus, I might be wrong.

Comment: Btw. there could be a whitelist of well-known, legit URL shorteners from whom `og` content is being utilized. This again is just a wild theory, but could actually happen to be the case?

Comment: @DanielKaplan What URL are you requesting (ie. _sharing_) exactly? Where is your `.htaccess` file? "I have a specific directory" - is `/myfavrockgroup` literally a physical subdirectory or just a (virtual) URL-path? Have you confirmed the redirect is working as intended, ie. a single redirect, no redirect _chain_? FWIW, this _should_ already work OK (and I've just tried it with the exact target URL you are using and the same directive in `.htaccess`), so there must be something else going on here. (?)

Comment: "no API dealing with any sort of Apache redirects can handle meta tags." - you can simply define a custom 301 `ErrorDocument` to customise the 301 HTTP response _body_ in which you can define any number of "meta tags". HOWEVER, this is generally pointless. Any compliant HTTP client/user-agent should not be looking at "meta tags" in the "redirect" response body in order to define the redirect "target". Most compliant user-agents do not even download the response _body_ when receiving a 3xx HTTP response status. @Levente